# Calling a procedure in an application from a DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, callback

I am trying to figure out how to call a procedure in an application from a DLL (not how to call a procedure in the DLL). Both the application and the DLL are developed with Delphi 11.

1. As an example, in the main application I have a procedure like the following:

   ```pascal
   procedure DrawRectangle( X, Y, W, H: Integer );
   var
     MyRect: TRectangle;
   begin
     MyRect := TRectangle.Create( mainForm );
     //and so on...
   end;
   ```
2. In the DLL I want to call the application's procedure:

   ```pascal
   DrawRectangle( 10, 10, 100, 100 );
   ```

Any help with a simple example would be very much appreciated. I have searched and read several articles online and still cannot get a grasp of how to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: [Writing Dynamically Loaded Libraries](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Writing_Dynamically_Loaded_Libraries)

Comment: @PeterWolf that does not answer the question.

Comment: You will need to pass a pointer to this procedure to the DLL. I haven't got a ready made example otherwise I would have made this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: export the procedure from the host executable using the exports keyword. Then use GetModule(nil) to get the module handle of the host executable. The use GetProcAddress to get the exported function.

Comment: Linking "_read several articles_" would help, as then we can further pinpoint what you actually want and hasn't been covered in those. @DavidHeffernan I know that executables can export, too, but OP sounds (and the tag indicates) like wanting a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just like setting a callback in general. Just combine [writing a DLL](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Writing_Dynamically_Loaded_Libraries) with defining [procedural types](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Procedural_Types_(Delphi)):

```pascal
library Lib;

type
  // The callback must be defined type as procedure or function,
  // so the compiler knows all parameters and the calling convention.
  // The name is only relevant to the type, not the procedure.
  TProcDrawRectangle= procedure( X, Y, W, H: Integer ); stdcall;

var
  // The pointer which either got something assigned to call or not.
  ProcToCall: TProcDrawRectangle= nil;

// We call this to pass (the pointer to a) procedure which this DLL
// can later call on its own to execute the procedure elsewhere.
procedure LinkMyCallback( proc: TProcDrawRectangle ); stdcall;
begin
  ProcToCall:= proc;
end;

// However, when/where the callback is executed is up to you.
procedure OtherThings(); stdcall;
begin
  //...
  if Assigned( ProcToCall ) then ProcToCall( 10, 20, 800, 600 );
end;

exports
  LinkMyCallback,
  OtherThings;

begin
end.
```

Now do the same in your program, along with importing the DLL's procedures:

```pascal
program Main;

type
  // The same definition as in the library, of course. Naturally you would put this
  // once in a unit, which is then used by both: your program and the DLL.
  TProcDrawRectangle= procedure( X, Y, W, H: Integer ); stdcall;

  // Statically linking the procedure (or functions) which are exported by the library.
  procedure LinkMyCallback( proc: TProcDrawRectangle ); stdcall; external 'Lib.dll';
  procedure OtherThings(); stdcall; external 'Lib.dll';

// Will be called from the library.
procedure CallbackHere( X, Y, W, H: Integer ); stdcall;
begin
  //DrawRectangle( X, Y, W, H: Integer );
end;

begin
  // Hand over (a pointer to) the procedure which it wants to call
  // at a later time.
  LinkMyCallback( CallbackHere );

  // Now is a "later time": executing this library's procedure will in
  // turn call on the DLL side the procedure pointer, which is then
  // executing "CallbackHere()" in this program.
  OtherThings();
end.
```

Keep an eye on making all exported procedures/functions using the same [calling convention](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Calling_Conventions) - Delphi works best with `stdcall`. Avoid using Delphi-only types like `String` or classes/objects in general - better use simple types and helper functions to indirectly operate with objects. Do's and don'ts when working with DLLs is a different topic.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can this be done dynamically?

Comment: Yes, of course, because that's unbound to your problem. Dynamically linking a DLL instead of statically is already partly explained in one of the linked articles, and you should find [tons of answeres here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+%5Bdll%5D+dynamic) or elsewhere on the internet about that. It was not part of your question. Solve your problems separately, then combine everything.

Comment: I cannot get this to work in a windows application. Your example is a console application. Would it be too much trouble to convert it to a windows application using dynamic loading? Thank you.

Comment: A `program`, a `library` and a `unit` all have the same core elements: defining types and procedures/functions and declaring variables - likewise it doesn't matter if an example is dealing with windows (`TForm`s) or not. If you're unable to turn any `begin ... end` into its own procedure or just putting its content at any place you want then you should learn Pascal more - almost no adaption skills are required for this. And your Q didn't specify the kind of program. Spoon-fed answers feel like unpaid delegated (home)work.

Answer (score -2):

***NOTE**: If your application must "expose" a method to draw a rectangle that can be called from an external DLL (DLL-1), I think the easiest thing to do is to extract that method to an external DLL (DLL-2). This way you can call the draw method existing in DLL-1, both from the application and from DLL-2.*

This is a simple example to see the minimum you need. It can be expanded and improved, but it works as it is.

First you must define the `DLL` project with paint functions, like this:

```
library Figuras;

uses
  ShareMem,
  VCL.Dialogs, VCL.Forms;

{$R *.res}

function rectangle(x,y,w,h:integer; Form:TForm):Integer; stdcall; overload;
begin
  Form.Canvas.Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
  Exit;
end;

exports rectangle(x,y,w,h:integer;Form:TForm);

end.
```

I have defined one function for draw a **Rectangle** inside a `TForm`. Tform is a parameter that you need to pass to the function/procedure.

Now, you nedd a project to call this DLL.
Create a simple proyect with a form and a button inside it, with this code:

```
unit UDibujar;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

function rectangle(x,y,w,h:integer;Form:TForm):Integer; stdcall; external 'figuras.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Call the DLL function/procedure
  rectangle(200,20,100,100,Self);
end;

end.
```

When you execute this project, the DLL method draw a `rectangle` inside the `form` that  make the call.
The result looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the example. This shows how to call the procedure from the application and not the DLL. My requirement is not triggered by an event in the application.

Comment: Sorry, I have read and I have not translated the question correctly.

Comment: If your application must "expose" a method to draw a rectangle that can be called from an external DLL (DLL-1), I think the easiest thing to do is to extract that method to an external DLL (DLL-2). This way you can call the draw method existing in DLL-1, both from the application and from DLL-2